# How to get the latest 10 changes from a CMIS repository

Tags: cmis

How to get the latest 10 changes that happened on a [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html) repository?

In particular, will the call to [getContentChanges](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-3190002) below return the latest 10 changes?
Or might it return the first 10 changes of the repo, or something else?

```
Integer maxItems = 10
getContentChanges(repositoryId, maxItems) // I don't specify a change token
```